# is it a good strlcat() implementation?

Tags: c, strings

I'd like to know if i respect strlcat(3) behiour with my implementation, cause i'm not really sure to understand strlcat particular behaviour

```
int my_strlcat(char *dest, char *src, int size)
{
  int i;
  int src_len;
  int dest_len;

  i = 0;
  dest_len = strlen(dest);
  src_len = strlen(src);
  if (size <= 0)
   return dest_len;
  while (dest_len < size)
  {
    dest[dest_len] = src[i];
    dest_len++;
    i++;
  }
  dest[dest_len] = '\0';
  return (strlen(dest));
}
```

Comment: In general, using signed types for sizes and anything but size_t for things of arbitrary size is a bad idea.

Comment: If dest does not already contain a nil-terminated string, or contains one that overflows dest (e.g. because someone previously used strcat()), then strlen() could return a value larger than size and you're already boned. You should replace the strlen() call with some code of your own that stops counting when it reaches size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (dest_len < size)
  {
    dest[dest_len] = src[i];
    dest_len++;
    i++;
  }
dest[dest_len] = '\0';
```

At the end of the loop dest_len will be equal to size, and the dest[des_len] will write beyond the allowed offset.

UPDATE: this will probably work

```
size_t my_strlcat(char *dest, char *src, size_t size)
{
size_t src_len, dest_len;

  dest_len = strlen(dest);
  src_len = strlen(src);

  if (dest_len+src_len>= size) return dest_len+src_len;

  memcpy(dest+dest_len, src, src_len+1);

  return dest_len+src_len;
}
```

Comment: This is inefficient, you end up iterating over `src` twice, making this not `O(N + M)` but `O(N + M*2)`.

Answer (score 2):

- `src_len` is not used..
- the `strlen` in the return statement is not needed.. you know the length from `dest_len`.

IMHO very weird implementation :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things wrong if this is meant to be a implementation of the standard [`strlcat()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strlcat/):

- The function definition should be of the form: `size_t my_strlcat(char *dst, const char *src, size_t size);`
- You are always overflowing the destination buffer by one when you NUL terminate.
- You are overflowing the source buffer reads depending on the input. For example, consider if `dest_len=1`, `src_len=2` and `size=1000`.
- While not wrong it is better to try to minimize the use of `strlen()` unless needed. You probably only need one `strlen(dest)`.

See [here](http://src.gnu-darwin.org/src/sys/libkern/strlcat.c.html) for an example implementation of strlcat().

Answer (score 0):

You're basically right I think. Checking the man page for `strlcpy()` shows one discrepancy I can see - the null termination of the destination only happens if there's room in `dest` after the copying. Although that seems kind of dangerous to me, it depends how well you want to replicate the semantics. Your current implementation always null-terminates, which is nice and safe but might end up diverging from the stock implementation in that edge case.

For performance, you should check `size <= 0` before you `strlen()` both of the strings, as in that case you only need to call `strlen(dest)`. That might seem minor, but `strlen` runs in O(N) time so you don't want to be calling it if you don't have to. So basically just move the check on `size` to before the call to `strlen(src)`.